# Moving RAID 5 to new motherboard

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, raid

I'm moving a RAID 5 controlled with an Areca ARC-1110 PCI RAID card to a new motherboard.  How do I ensure my array stays intact through the move?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to your question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/61823/moving-a-raid-array-from-one-machine-to-another)

Quote:

> If you have a dedicated RAID controller that plugs into a PCI port,
>   then you should be fine. All of the RAID data will be stored on the
>   controller, with matching meta-data on the drives. Then you can just
>   move the whole thing into another server. Some controllers will even
>   let you shuffle the drives around so that they don't need to go back
>   in the same order that they came out in (particularly useful when you
>   have 14 disks).
>
> If you are using software-based RAID (i.e. in Windows or Linux), then
>   this too can be transported between machines. With Windows, when you
>   put all the new disks in, it will ask you to import them and they
>   should just start running without a hitch. With Linux I don't know the
>   procedure but I suspect it would be something similar.
>
> If you are using an on-board RAID controller, this is where things can
>   get tricky. You have specified that you will be moving between
>   different hardware, so if you were moving from say an Adaptec RAID
>   controller to a 3Ware controller, then the chances of survival are
>   minimal. If both the boards have the same brand of controller, they
>   may be able to read the meta-data off the disks and re-create the
>   array.
>
> If you're VERY brave, you can create a new array on the new
>   controller, and make sure that you use the exact same settings as the
>   previous controller used (same stripe size, etc), and when it asks you
>   if you want to initialise the array, say no, and hope for the best.
>   I've had this work with a RAID0 and a RAID10, but never with a RAID5.
>
> So the short answer is - if you want to be able to move it around
>   easily, invest a hundred bucks into a proper RAID controller and just
>   move the whole thing over in one hit.

Comment: The OP has a PCI card. I'd only quote the first alinea. The rest might be confusing and/or distracting.